# Marklogic 8 : Count documents per collection and/or directory

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

I have 50 Millions document in my marklogic database. I'd like to analyze the content in order to know which are the main categories of document.

Each of my document are in a specific folder (ie : "/books/") and with a specific collection ("/type/books").

I'd like to generate a CSV with two columns : name_of_the_collection;count_distinct_value

Example :

```
Collection;count
books;437438
cars;46565
cats;457373
```

And the same with the directory :

```
directory;count
/animals/cats/;437438
/animals/dogs;46565
/animals/cow;457373
```

I tried to list all distinct categories/collection and count the number of documents but I was not able to combine the two.

Could you please help me ?

Thanks,
Romain.

Answer (score 7):

Given a name of a collection `xdmp:estimate(cts:search(doc(), cts:collection-query($collection))` will give you a count of the number of documents in that collection. Similarly with `cts:directory-query($directory)` for a directory.

If you have the collection lexicon enabled you can get all the collection counts directly: `cts:collections()!text{.||";"||cts:count(.)}`

For directories it is a little trickier, but if you have the URI collection enabled you can get the directories with a bit of work as well:

```
declare function local:basepath( 
  $uri as xs:string
) as xs:string
{
   if ( fn:contains( $uri, "/" ) )
   then 
      let $path := fn:replace( $uri, "^(.*)/([^/]*)$", "$1" )
      return if ($path = "") then "/" else $path
   else ""
};

let $map := map:map()
let $_ :=
  for $uri in cts:uris()
  let $dir := local:basepath($uri)
  return
    if (empty(map:get($map, $dir)))
    then map:put($map, $dir, 1)
    else map:put($map, $dir, map:get($map,$dir)+1)
for $key in map:keys($map)
return ($key||";"||map:get($map,$key))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example in XQuery

```
for $coll in cts:collections()
  let $count := fn:count(cts:uris("",(),cts:collection-query($coll)))
  order by $count descending
  return fn:concat($coll,';',$count)
```

Comment: This part: `cts:uris("",(),$coll)` needs to be this instead: `cts:uris("",(),cts:collection-query($coll))`. Otherwise you'll be searching for the collection name as a term.